# how to translate curl into javascript POST request

Tags: javascript, curl, fetch, fetch-api

I am trying to connect to payment api named PayU, they provide example on how to connect via curl one is to connect via rest api

```
curl -X POST https://secure.payu.com/pl/standard/user/oauth/authorize \
-d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=145227&client_secret=12f071174cb7eb79d4aac5bc2f07563f'
```

and one is to connect via SDK which I would also like to use, but this one needs additional settings in the shop, and I'm having trouble with the first one so if someone would be kind enough to decipher the other one as well would be great

```
curl -X POST https://secure.payu.com/pl/standard/user/oauth/authorize \
   -H "Cache-Control: no-cache"
   -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
   -d 'grant_type=trusted_merchant&client_id=[provided by PayU]&client_secret=[provided by PayU]&email=[users email]&ext_customer_id=[Id of the customer used in merchant system]'
```

In curl the first one delivered the token without problems, however I am trying to do this same in code, and I am unable to. This is my code:

```
fetch('https://secure.payu.com/pl/standard/user/oauth/authorize', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        'client_id': '145227',
        'client_secret': '12f071174cb7eb79d4aac5bc2f07563f',
    })

  }).then(res => {
        if (!res.ok) {
          throw new Error("Fetching payU failed, please try again later!");
        }
        return res;
      })
      .then(data => {
       console.log(data)
       return { payUdata: data }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
       
      });
```

Comment: To add to @Skarlinski, replace `body: JSON.stringify(...)` with something like `body: new URLSearchParams(Object.entries({your_object})).toString();`. Also, add headers to your options to specify content-type: `headers: {"content-type": "application/x-www-url-encoded"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic Post body isn't a serialized json, data looks like query params, just like in the curl

```
{
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'},
    body: "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=145227&client_secret=12f071174cb7eb79d4aac5bc2f07563f")
}
```

from @BankBuilder comment:

```
function querifyObject(obj){
 return new URLSearchParams(Object.entries(obj)).toString();
}
```

and then:

```
{
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'},
        body: querifyObject({
          'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
          'client_id': '145227',
          'client_secret': '12f071174cb7eb79d4aac5bc2f07563f',
        })
    }
```

[image: Working screenshot]

Comment: Hi @BankBuilder and Skarlinksi thank you very much for your answers however it still does not work ;/ I thought it is irrelevant, but I am trying to use it in svelte and sapper in the server side code (querifyObject fn did not change anything either)

Comment: without thens my code looks like this <script context="module">

  export function preload(page) {
    return this.fetch('https://secure.payu.com/pl/standard/user/oauth/authorize', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {"content-type": "application/x-www-url-encoded"},
    body: "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=145227&client_secret=12f071174cb7eb79d4aac5bc2f07563f",
  })}
</script>

Comment: The error comes from if check - if (!res.ok)

Comment: @Seven I'm getting a 401 - unauthorized, also when running the curl. Maybe an issue with the credentials?

Comment: @Seven Had a typo in my headers field, fixed now & tested. BTW, make sure you don't have a cors issue

Comment: thanks, I had CORS on client side, but this is fetched is server side code in script tag with context="module" prop, so there should be no cors, however I have just logged res in my if !res.ok check, and it actually returns 401 unauthorized, so it must be something with my credentials not fetch. Thanks for bothering to double-check it on your side :) I will triple-check it on mine and perhaps contact their support in that case

Comment: @Seven Check out my screenshot, got 200 + ok:true. also look at the correction I made in the headers

Comment: I tried yesterday with the headers on, and it gave me status 200, however it does not return a token but some weird response

Comment: I have to split it in two:
Response {
  size: 0,
  timeout: 0,
  [Symbol(Body internals)]: {
    body: PassThrough {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kCallback)]: null
    },
    disturbed: false,
    error: null
  },

Comment: [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
    url: 'https://secure.payu.com/pl/standard/user/oauth/authorize',
    status: 200,
    statusText: 'OK',
    headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] },
    counter: 0
  }
}